# Multipe DataSet Values in one Row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a Report in SSRS 2008 that looks like so:

[image]

For the Sales Attendees and Other Attendees it may have more than one person that needs to go in that row. As you can see from the screenshot right now it just creates another row. How would I make it so they go into the same row instead of creating new rows?

EDIT: I have to use FetchXML. I'm working against CRM 2011.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brent D mentions, I would rather do this in the data source, but you can do the same thing with the [RunningValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159136.aspx) function and [some custom code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suryaj/archive/2007/08/11/string-aggregation.aspx). ([Another blog entry](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/chintak/archive/2011/01/08/string-concatenation-aggregation-in-ssrs-column-or-row-group.aspx) using the same approach.)

Write the custom code to take in additional strings and add them to the end of a stored string. It will need a second parameter, so you know when to clear out the stored string and start over for the next group.

Once you've got this working, you can use this in a group footer, and then hide your data rows.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I can do it in the DataSet because I am using FetchXML and I'm not so sure I can use RunningValue since I need strings instead of ints.

Answer (score 0):

You could try concatenating the names with a comma in the sql datasource by doing something like:

```
Select <main data columns, e.g. RSM/NAM,AppointmentDate,etc>
    ,stuff((select ','+SalesAttendee From tableB Where TableA.ID=TableB.ID For XML Path('')),1,1,'')
From TableA
```

See [SQL Concatenation](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/concatenate-using-xml-path.aspx) for reference.

Comment: Thanks. I have to use FetchXML. I'm working against CRM 2011.